# How can I make social-icon visible?

Tags: html, css

My social-icon(link) worked and was visible. And suddenly it disappeared and didn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="social-icon"><a href="https://www.t.me/ta_kotoraya_ta" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
.social-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 885px;
  right: 2px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.social-icon a {
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  color: rgba(14,13,13);
}
.social-icon a:hover {
  color: rgb(250, 3, 3);
}
```

https://codepen.io/tatarusetskaya/pen/XWpzNZa

Comment: check if you have fontavesome in your project.

Comment: This script is missing in your html file. Add the below line and it will show up.
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't import Font Awesome. Add this to the `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

[Result](https://jsfiddle.net/yxc0tmd5/)

Comment: Thank you! It is visible, but doesn't work as a link and hover doesn't work too. Can you help and answer why? Thanks.

Comment: @TataRusetskaya It appears that the margin from the header is overlaying the icon. I'll continue investigating.

Comment: it works, if i delete margin of social-icon a. But in tis case I need to replace .social-icon, and when i did it, it didn't work. It works only when .social-icon right: 2px. And margin of social-icon a is deleted, And I need social-icon: 10px.